# em dash in this sentence, is it used as an alternative for comma (,) esp in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

This is especially important for writers who are non-native English speakers—try to find native English speakers to review your writing.

Comment: In that sentence it appears to be substituting for a colon.

Comment: @Robusto - I see we disagree. You say colon. I say semicolon. Could you perhaps give your reasoning and/or give a critique of my answer. (I'll try to find an authoritative source for my claim).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I don't think we disagree, I just think my interpretation may be broader than yours. One of the uses of a colon is to set off material that is a direct result or follow-on of the (usually) independent clause that precedes it. "This rule keep in your heart: always be faithful." That said, using a semicolon there feels weak to me. So maybe there is some disagreement after all. ^_^

Comment: I think maybe the author of the phrase was wise to use an em dash—no-one could argue with that!

Comment: I would also use a colon. Or write either *Especially important for writers who are non-native English speakers is to find native English speakers to review their writing* or *Finding native English speakers to review their writing is especially important for writers who are not native English speakers.* Or: *Non-native speakers would do well to find native English speakers to review their writing.*

Answer (score 2):

> This is especially important for writers who are non-native English speakers—try to find native English speakers to review your writing.

This could be a full-stop (period):

*This is especially important for writers who are non-native English speakers. Try to find native English speakers to review your writing.*

or it could be a semicolon:

*This is especially important for writers who are non-native English speakers; try to find native English speakers to review your writing.*

A comma is not strong enough to separate independent clauses.

**Edit**

There is a case for using a colon as well. See the comment by Robusto.

Comment: I see. so you mean sir, if that's a dependent clause probably I can use comma (,) or em dash (--) for separation.

Comment: Did you write the original phrase? The em dash is correct in that situation.  Yes, a comma can be used with a dependent clause. However there isn't a dependent clause in your example so you can't use it there.